# How can i "run" application via Maven?

Tags: java, maven-2

I am playing with Maven and was wondering whether i can run my program using `mvn` command from either a command line or eclipse.

I am able to do a clean install, but no run so far.

Comment: http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for what we have the '[maven-exec-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/)'.